# Domain Modelling Help: Product & ProductType & ProductyTypeProperties & ProductyTypePropertyValues

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-structures, domain-driven-design, data-modeling

I have a problem domain where user should be able to create a "ProductType" object where each ProductType object should have a list of "ProductTypeProperties" aggregated and each ProductTypeProperty object should have a list of "ProductTypePropertyValues" aggregated.

After it user is able to create a "Product" object and associate few ProductTypes with it.

When user associates Product with few ProductTypes, user is able to specify values of ProductTypeProperties to the Product object.

ProductTypeProperties could have values that belongs to different select modes, like: "one-choose", "multiple-choose" and "string / integer / decimal input"

I'm not sure how to design such domain object model. Especially how to apply ProductType's property values on Product object.

I don't mind about persistence at this time, only about object domain model, as I'm free to choose SQL/Document/Object/Graph database.

The object structure now looks like this:

```
ProductType
    List<ProductTypeProperty>
        List<ProductTypePropertyValue>

Product
    List<ProductType>
```

The C# classes definition I use for now is:

```
public class Product {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ProductType> AssociatedProductTypes { get; set; }
    // how to apply ProductType's property values to a Product object?
}

public class ProductType {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ProductTypeProperty> AggregatedProperties { get; set; }
}

public class ProductTypeProperty {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ProductTypePropertyValue> AggregatedAvailableValues { get; set; }
}

public class ProductTypePropertyValue {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

It looks like trying to apply Class/Object structure in objects, where "ProductType" is a "class" and "Product" is an "object" that can be an instance "ProductTypes" and "inherit" properties and available values from each of associated product types.

I was never doing an object model like this, so it's very interesting how to do it right.
Thanks for any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: It seems that you have already an objects model that reflects correctly the structure you are looking for (products with several product types, product types with several properties, properties with several possible values). If you already modeled it, what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can map the ProductTypeProperty as follows:

A generic base property class, where TValue will determine the type of property value (could be string, decimal, int, or multiple choice):

```
    public abstract class ProductTypePropertyBase<TValue>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }

        protected ProductTypePropertyBase(string name, TValue value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
```

for each type of property create a nested class, for example for a simple string property you can create:

```
public class ProductTypeStringProperty : ProductTypePropertyBase<string>
{
    public ProductTypeStringProperty(string name, string value) : base(name, value)
    {
    }
}
```

for a complex property type like multiple choices you can implement:

```
public class ProductTypeMultipleChoiceProperty : ProductTypePropertyBase<MultipleChoiceValue>
{
    public ProductTypeMultipleChoiceProperty(string name, MultipleChoiceValue value) : base(name, value)
    {
    }
}
```

where MultipleChoiceValue is another type that represents a list of strings for example.